# How to create a custom navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I want to create my own custom navigation bar on my HTML website.

For example:
https://www.bittersweetcandybowl.com/archive.html
https://www.sleeplessdomain.com/

(The Navigatertwo is the custom navigation bar)

I tried doing what they did like copying some of the code but it doesn't seem to work.

```css
* body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
  background-image: url("Navigatertwo.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 75px;
  width: 770px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 25%;
  /* Four links of equal widths */
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="mainnav">
    <div class="mainnav">
      <li><a href="ArchiveTwo.html" class="mainnav_about"><span class="titletext"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="About.html" class="mainnav_archive"><span class="titletext"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="Extras.html" class="mainnav_extras"><span class="titletext"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="Characters.html" class="mainnav_characters"><span class="titletext"></span></a></li>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Nav.css">
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need mention the issue clearly; what does not work? Please refer the [ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem. Copy this code and paste into your project

```css
ul#nav {
 list-style: none;
 height: 134px;
 position: relative;
 background-image: url(https://blasto.enterprises/img/global_header_rainbow_club_noschedule_lighter.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 padding-left: 0;
 margin: -15px 0 0;
}
ul#nav li a {
 height: 55px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
a.nav_about {
 width: 125px;
 height: 55px!important;
 top: 45px;
 left: 25px;
}
a.nav_archive {
 width: 146px;
 top: 35px;
 left: 162px;
}
a.nav_extras {
 width: 123px;
 top: 36px;
 left: 325px;
}
a.nav_candybooru {
 width: 223px;
 top: 47px;
 left: 467px;
}
a.nav_club {
 width: 95px;
 top: 50px;
 left: 706px;
}
a.nav_store {
 width: 108px;
 height: 56px!important;
 top: 38px;
 left: 809px;
}
.titletext {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="" class="nav_about"><span class="titletext">About</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav_archive"><span class="titletext">Archive</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav_extras"><span class="titletext">Extras</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav_candybooru"><span class="titletext">Candybooru</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav_club"><span class="titletext">Club</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav_store"><span class="titletext">Store</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so i replaced the background image:https://blasto.enterprises/img/global_header_rainbow_club_noschedule_lighter.png with (/Navigatertwo.jpg); and the image is not showing in the back of the letters am i missing something here

Comment: yes u have to replace copy entire code and paste into ur project

Comment: the image Navigatertwo.jpg is not showing  when i replaced it (the background of the navigation)

Comment: this is what i put background-image: url (img_Navigatertwo.jpg);

Comment: show me image which image u want to add into background

Comment: https://blasto.enterprises/img/global_header_rainbow_club_noschedule_lighter.png      open this link u will get idea about this

Comment: how do i add an image here?